# Відповідники до слова "слінг"

Tags: вживання-слів

***Слінг*** - *шматок тканини, призначений для носіння немовлят на грудях матері.*

На сайті [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/sling) пропонують декілька відповідників до слова ***"слінг"***:

> плекальце
>
> кубельце
>
> сповивач
>
> ворочок

На мою думку найкраще підходить слово **["сповивач"](http://sum.in.ua/s/spovyvach)** або навіть замінити на **["повивач"](http://sum.in.ua/s/povyvach)**

> Довгий вузький шматок тканини для сповивання немовляти.

Яке із слів краще вживати? Чи, можливо, слово ***"слінг"*** вже є в якихось академічних виданнях (я не знайшла)? Можливо, нормативно вживати саме слово ***"слінг"***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знайшла інформацію на одному з медичних [порталів](http://mediclab.com.ua/index.php?newsid=27658) :

> **Пов'язка Підтримуюча** **(Sling)** - пов'язка, призначена для підтримки та забезпечення спокою травмованої кінцівки, так щоб процесу одужання не заважала її фізична активність.

Даний Вами термін у вищенаведеному прикладі поданий у трішки іншому контексті, але це пов'язано з великою кількістю різновидів слінгів. Однак, цікавить нас те, що у дужках коло українського відповідника (який складається з 2-х слів) бачимо англійське слово. Очевидно, в цьому випадку  в українській мові маємо справу з [матеріальним запозиченням](http://pidruchniki.com/1156052248100/dokumentoznavstvo/zapozichennya). І не зважаючи на українські відповідники, це слово є більш поширеним. Щодо наявності цього слова у словниках, то, очевидно, що ми ще "не встигли" внести його у реєстр, але воно є нормативним.

Також, на мою думку, можна використовувати такі  українські відповідники: [перев'язь, тканинний утримувач](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B3).